# How can I host a website externally from home using public an ip address?

Tags: iis, iis-7, hosting, web-hosting, windows-server-2008-r2

please help a newbie out
I have installed windows server 2008 r2 and IIS at home, I also purchased a domain through godaddy.com I would like host a simple html file on this domain, my ISP provider is Cox and I dont have a static IP dedicated. my server is hooked up to a router. any help or tutorial would be highly appreciated.

questions:
is there any forwarding needed, if so how?
how can I enable any ports? or enable firewall on windows server?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Sure, that's possible. Try this:

1. Assign your home server a static IP address so your router doesn't give it a new one when its DHCP lease expires.
2. Forward the port you're running IIS on from the outside world (DMZ) to that static IP
3. Setup an account with no-ip.com and install their app. You'll get a subdomain like omg.no-ip.com
4. Log in to GoDaddy's panel and set a CNAME for your domain, so traffic to your domain goes to that no-ip address above, which the windows client keeps updated

This is how I have it setup at home, despite the fact I have a static now.